# DNN Enhanced Permission Provider - All Users Blank Content

Tags: permissions, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

Has anyone out there used this for DNN7?

Currently no one can view the page content (so HTML modules and other things on the page) but you can navigate to different pages using the navigation. Basically for "All Users", they cannot view the page content.

However when I login as Admin or Host, I can see all the content fine. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: did you check page permissions on one of the pages? Or permissions in general?

Comment: yes, I tried just one page to try get it working but the content just appears blank. I thought maybe the default HTML module itself requires permission update but im not sure how to look for that. It's just strange admin/root can see the content but for All Users the content is blank. It's like All Users are not given View permission but they are.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third party module, it would make sense to take it up with the developer.